# C# - How to detect whether a website has a Shared or Dedicated IP Address?

Tags: c#, .net, ip

Is it possible to detect whether a website has a dedicated or shared ip address from it's url using C# (Windows Forms application) ? I want to implement a functionality in my application to let write a web address in a TextBox than i click on the Test button. and then show ( Success ) MessageBox if the site has a Dedicated ip address or show a ( Failure ) MessageBox otherwise.

How can i detect whether a website has a Shared or Dedicated IP Address using C#.NET?

Comment: The only way to be able to determine that is to have historical context. An IP address is indistinguishable from any other IP address in terms of shared or dedicated. You'd need to store some history.

Answer (score 2):

You can try, but you'll never have a good result. The best I think you could do is to check the PTR records of the IP, and then check if there are associated A records from different websites. This would still suck however, since a website could have two seemingly different domains that pertain to the same organization (googlemail.com/gmail.com for example).

Also, this assumes the existence of PTR records, multiple ones. I don't think I've seen such a setup supported by most VPS/sharing hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way I would do it is:

1. Send HTTP GET to the URL and save the result.
2. Resolve the URL to an IP.
3. Send HTTP GET to the IP and save the result.
4. Compare the two results. (You can do sample checks between the two result)
5. If the results are the same, then this is dedicated hosting, if the result is different then this is a shared hosting.

Limitations for this method that I can think of now:

1. Will take you time to figure our a proper comparing method for the
   two results.
2. If shared hosting is configured to default route to the site which you are checking.

Functions to resolve URLs, and do web requests for different programming languages are scattered across the Internet.

Comment: A dedicated server can still have multiple sites.

Comment: Dear Josh, if by sites you mean: domain.com/site1, domain.com/site2, then these are folders in origin not sites, and I am not sure if according to shared IP hosting standards it is correct to assume this is shared hosting.

Comment: Another thing, if you change the original question to dedicated server or shared server, my technique would not work in one more case. If the server has multiple physical adapters, and each website is assigned to each adapter individually, then my technique would fail to determine if it is a shared or dedicated server.

Comment: No, I mean if my organization has a dedicated server, we could still set up multiple sites on that server.  (IE, example.com/example.org)  Both domains would resolve to the same IP, and this method would identify one of them as "shared hosting" even though they're both served by the organization's dedicated server.

Comment: Hi Josh, would example.com and example.org would result in the same website being displayed? If yes, my technique would still identify the IP as a dedicated IP. If no, my technique would show them as shared hosting (because in that case it is the very definition of shared hosting)

Comment: Also Josh, I tested my technique for the issue you proposed on  yahoo.com and yahoo.org, it resulted in dedicated hosting for them.

Comment: No.  A more concrete example: a company hosts its regular website on *company.com*, where they market their great widgets.  On the same server, they also host *companyjobs.com*, where they have their job postings.  The company owns one dedicated server (on which they host multiple sites), **but this is not *shared hosting*.**  Shared hosting is when a service provider hosts the website of multiple (usually unrelated) customers on a single box.  Dedicated hosting is when a single entity has full control over a box provided by a provider; the number of sites hosted by that entity is immaterial.

Comment: I see your point here Josh, but referring back to Shikata's question, he wanted to know if the IP is being shared by multiple sites, not necessary it is a service provider case. So for the case you proposed, it falls under Shikata's question. From another point of perspective though, service provider => multiple users sharing same server, your scenario => multiple sites sharing same server, so in both cases it is a sharing scenario. A slightly reliable workaround solution for the scenario you indicated, compare the registrars for both domains, if they are the same, then consider it dedicated.

Answer (score 0):

From a technical standpoint, there's no such thing as a "shared" or "dedicated" IP address; the protocol makes no distinction.  Those are terms used to describe *how* an IP is used.

As such, there's no programmatic method to answer "is this shared or dedicated?"  Some of the other answers to this question suggest some ways to **guess** whether a particular domain is on a shared IP, but those methods are at best guesses.

If you really want to go down this road, you could crawl the web and store resolved IPs for every domain.  (Simple, right?)  Then you could query your massive database for all the domains hosted on a given IP.  ([There](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/) [are](http://www.domainbyip.com/) [tools](http://www.myipneighbors.com/) that seem to do this already, although only the first one was able to identify the multiple domains I have hosted on my server.)

Of course, this is all for naught with VPS (or things like Amazon EC2) where the server hardware itself is shared, but every customer (domain) gets one or more dedicated IPs.  From the outside, there's no way to know how such servers are set up.

---

*TL;DR:* This can't be done in a reliable manner.